# ng filtering using scope defined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am developing a webpage using angular js. and i want to add some filter to the site,

here is my HTML code

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas | filter:{area:course} | filter:{subject:subFilter} | filter:{city:cityFilter}">
                        <h5><span class="text-warning">#</span>&nbsp;{{data.intrest}}</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <h5 class="text-info">Name</h5>
                                <p>{{data.name}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <h5 class="text-info">Subject</h5>
                                <p>{{data.subject}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                              <h5 class="text-info">Address</h5>
                                <p>{{data.city}}, {{data.state}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <a href="#/view"><button class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top:10px;">View</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
```

And this is my controller file

```
app.controller('mainController',['$scope','$http','$routeParams',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
$http.get('assets/newtab.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.department=data;
    $scope.whichItem=$routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.course=$scope.department[$scope.whichItem].course;
});
$http.get('assets/engineering.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.datas=data;
    $scope.whichItem=$routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.optItem=[
        {title:"Random",value:" "},
        {title:"Question Paper Setting",value:"Question Paper Setting"},
        {title:"Question Paper Passing Board",value:"Question Paper Passing Board"},
        {title:"Question Paper Post Auditing",value:"Question Paper Post Auditing"},
        {title:"Question Paper Evaluation",value:"Question Paper Evaluation"},
        {title:"Member for board of study",value:"Member for board of study"},
        {title:"Member for academic council",value:"Member for academic council"},
        {title:"Result passing board",value:"Result passing board"},
        {title:"Invigilation",value:"Invigilation"},
        {title:"Door Valuation",value:"Door Valuation"},
        {title:"Exam squad",value:"Exam squad"}
    ];
});
}]);
```

here goes the snippet from engineering.json and newtab.json

enginering.json

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Sam","dob":"","age":"21","gender":"","department":"16\/03\/1995","area":"Nuclear Medicine Technology Course","institution":"Park College of Technology ","city":"Tiruppur","state":"Tamil Nadu","intrest":"Question paper evaluation","mobile":"","email":"jaya5292.jmj@gmail.com","password":"jaya","subject":"Computer Networks"},{"id":"2","name":"jaya","dob":"","age":"21","gender":"","department":"16\/03\/1995","area":"Nuclear Medicine Technology Course","institution":"Park College of Technology ","city":"","state":"","intrest":"","mobile":"","email":"jaya5292.jmj@gmail.com","password":"jaya","subject":""},{"id":"3","name":"jaya","dob":"","age":"21","gender":"","department":"16\/03\/1995","area":"Nuclear Medicine Technology Course","institution":"Park College of Technology ","city":"","state":"","intrest":"","mobile":"","email":"jaya5292.jmj@gmail.com","password":"jjjj","subject":""}]
```

newtab.json

```
[{"Department":"Arts","course":"B.A. English"}, {"Department":"Arts","course":"B.A. English (Computer Applications)"}, {"Department":"Arts","course":"B.A. Economics"}, {"Department":"Arts","course":"B.A. History"}, {"Department":"Arts","course":"B.A. Political Science"}, {"Department":"Arts","course":" B.A. Tamil  "}, {"Department":"Arts","course":"B.Lit. Tamil  "}]
```

in my controller on line 5 i've fetched the value on clicked item and stored it in a variable named "course", i must be able to filter the result in my html using this "course". i wrote a syntax in my html file. but it is not filtering the proper result

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, the .area property for datas (enginering.json) does not overlap the .course property of newtab.  For each of the engineering.json, the area is "Nuclear Medicine Technology Course", so no matter what department you pick from newtab, there will be no match.

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/kvrd0cb8/4/).  In this fiddle, I've changed to .area of Sam to show that the filter works (and removed the additional filters for simplicity, though they should work fine).

But another possible problem is that the data returned from $http is usually accessed in the form

```
$http.get(url).then(function(result) {
    $scope.variable = result.data;
}
```

because the object returned from the $http call has the data in the .data property.  So that's something to look at, too.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @mzulch below, your $http syntax is correct for angular versions below 1.5

Comment: It appears to be deprecated as of angular 1.5, but `$http` supports the `success` promise method as an alternative to `then` and the callback receives as parameters `data, status, headers, config` instead of a single `response`

Comment: @mzulch, excellent point.  Thanks for reminding us of that!  My mistake.  Answer is updated

Comment: this fiddle doesn't seems helping me! will any provide an alternate sollution?

Comment: @Sam, can you give more information?  What's not working?  Is my fiddle not working?  What are the results you are getting and what are you trying to get?  Do you understand the fiddle?  If not, what part don't you understand?  Can you create a fiddle of your own that shows the problem?  Or give me enough information to create a fiddle that might help?

Comment: See, if you add {{course}} some where else other than within the filter it returns the correct value i.e if i click on B.E Computer science it returns B.E Computer science, and if i click B.Sc. Tamil it returns B.Sc. Tamil, now if i add the same {{course}} within the filter it is not returning the correct value, even if i click different link it returns the link that i have returned first i.e on clicking B.E Tamil, it still returns B.E. Computer Science

Comment: This unfortunately makes it hard to help -- I don't see anywhere in the code you've given that allows for any kind of on-click functionality, therefore I don't know what you mean when you say that 'when i click on...it returns...'  According to the code you have above, you are sorting the area property by what gets returned from the course property and that will never give you anything because the course property and the area property in the data you've given me never intersect.

Comment: In other words, none of the areas = B. E. Computer Science or B. Sc. Tamil, so even though the course is being set correctly, it will never work as a filter on area.  In fact, there doesn't seem to be any correlation between newtab.json and enginering.json -- how are they supposed to be related?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?